# Detect first occurrence by factor in a presence/absence table

Tags: r

I am investigating the residency times of 130 transmitters in a receiver array over a 94-day period. In other words, I am attempting to track how long each transmitter is detected in the study area. I was able to create a daily presence/absence table that identifies if any detections were recorded for each transmitter over the time period (0 = no detection, 1 = detection). All 130 transmitters were not deployed all at once but staggered until August 21st. The transmitters do not have the same deployment date since their deployments were spread out over time.

Question: Using R code, how would I identify the first day that each transmitter was detected from this presence/absence table?

If any of this is unclear, please feel free to ask any questions. You can find my example data set below with 5 transmitters and their daily presence from July to October.

```
dput(head(t))
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
95L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("9335", "9344", "9354", "9364", 
"9374"), c("2013-07-01", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-03", "2013-07-04", 
"2013-07-05", "2013-07-06", "2013-07-07", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-09", 
"2013-07-10", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-12", "2013-07-13", "2013-07-14", 
"2013-07-15", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-17", "2013-07-18", "2013-07-19", 
"2013-07-20", "2013-07-21", "2013-07-22", "2013-07-23", "2013-07-24", 
"2013-07-25", "2013-07-26", "2013-07-27", "2013-07-28", "2013-07-29", 
"2013-07-30", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-01", "2013-08-02", "2013-08-03", 
"2013-08-04", "2013-08-05", "2013-08-06", "2013-08-07", "2013-08-08", 
"2013-08-09", "2013-08-10", "2013-08-11", "2013-08-12", "2013-08-13", 
"2013-08-14", "2013-08-15", "2013-08-16", "2013-08-17", "2013-08-18", 
"2013-08-19", "2013-08-20", "2013-08-21", "2013-08-22", "2013-08-23", 
"2013-08-24", "2013-08-25", "2013-08-26", "2013-08-27", "2013-08-28", 
"2013-08-29", "2013-08-30", "2013-08-31", "2013-09-01", "2013-09-02", 
"2013-09-03", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-05", "2013-09-06", "2013-09-07", 
"2013-09-08", "2013-09-09", "2013-09-10", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-12", 
"2013-09-13", "2013-09-14", "2013-09-15", "2013-09-16", "2013-09-17", 
"2013-09-18", "2013-09-19", "2013-09-20", "2013-09-21", "2013-09-22", 
"2013-09-23", "2013-09-24", "2013-09-25", "2013-09-26", "2013-09-27", 
"2013-09-28", "2013-09-29", "2013-09-30", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-02", 
"2013-10-03")), .Names = c("", "")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, for each row you're looking for the column name with the first (from the left) occurrence of `1`. A few first columns in your data set look like:

```
       2013-07-01 2013-07-02 2013-07-03 2013-07-04 2013-07-05 
  9335          0          0        *1*          1          1 
  9344          0          0        *1*          1          1 
  9354          0          0        *1*          1          1 
  9364         *1*         1         1           1          1 
  9374         *1*         1         0           0          0
```

Assuming your data frame is named `df`, here's a solution:

```
colnames(df)[apply(df, 1, which.max)]
## [1] "2013-07-03" "2013-07-03" "2013-07-03" "2013-07-01" "2013-07-01"
```

Explanation:

1. `apply(df, 1, which.max)` returns the column number with the first occurrence of `1` (via `which.max`) in each row (`apply(..., 1, ...)`).
   I use `which.max` here as, each row consists only of `0`s and `1`s and trivially `0 < 1`. BTW, it won't work if there are no `1`s in some row.
2. These column numbers are used to retrieve the dates (via `colnames`).

Comment: Great! Thank you for the advice! Is there any way to expand upon this and output a data frame with the transmitter and first day side-by-side? Or am I to assume that the output of `colnames(df)[apply(df, 1, which.max)]` is listed in the same order as the transmitters in the table?

Comment: It'll also be easy (AFAIR there were similar questions on SO already). the solution can involve a call to `anyDuplicated`, for example. Something like `df$date[anyDuplicated(df$Transmitter]` (assuming that `df` is ordered by date)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `colnames(df)[max.col(df, "first")]` seems valid, too?

Comment: @alexis_laz: Seems true!